# How to build android studio app from github? (if it's android studio app ?)

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, apk

I tried to get a piano learning application from github, installed android studio but can't build the climprPianoPerformer.

Here is the github : https://github.com/Boman/ClimprPianoPerformer

I never used Android Studio before and don't really know what is happening.

[Here is the result i have when Building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1KhS.png)

I think Java and Gradle are installed correctly :

[gradel -v java -version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btESx.png)

Can someone help me ?

I tried to build the files and expected to get an .APK

Comment: Please don't post terminal output as screenshot. Text should be posted as text. Regarding your Gradle problems you have to know that older Android projects requirer an older Gradle versions and Java version (e.g. 8 or 11 or 17). Java 21 isn't supported at all. So make sure to have installed the matching Java versions, set JAVA_HOME accordingly and then execute on comand-line `./gradlew` to use the Gradle version the project specifies.